# Get Dimensions of Cell Comment Background Image (.Shape.Fill.UserPicture)

Tags: excel, image, vba

How do I get the dimensions of a cell comment background image?

I have created a comment composed solely of a background image using,

`ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture    l_strFullPathOfImagePNG`

I would like to be able to,

1. Select the cell.
2. Run a macro that resizes the comment so the background image is not fuzzy, but rather sized exactly pixel for pixel.

To do this I need to know the dimensions of the background image.

If I know the full path of the image file that created the background image, I can resize the cell comment to achieve what I want:

```
Sub CommentResizeToFitBackgroundImage()

   Dim l_strFullPathOfImagePNG As String
   Dim l_lImageWidth_pixels As Long, _
       l_lImageHeight_pixels As Long

   l_strFullPathOfImagePNG = "C:\……\BackgroundImage.png"

   'Get the width and height in pixels of the image to be inserted
   GetPNGDimensions _
         l_strFullPathOfImagePNG, _
         l_lImageWidth_pixels, _
         l_lImageHeight_pixels

   With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape

      '0.75 scale factor was arrived at empirically
      'and probably true only for my machine
      .Width = l_lImageWidth_pixels * 0.75
      .Height = l_lImageHeight_pixels * 0.75

   End With
End Sub
```

However, I would like to do this to existing comments that no longer have a valid image file to read, so I need to get the dimensions of the background image.

`.Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue` looks promising, but fails with the error "The RelativeToOriginalSize argument applies only to a picture or an OLE object".

`.Comment.Shape.Fill.Type` = `MsoFillType.msoFillPicture`; so I do indeed have a picture, and not a solid background, gradient, pattern, or texture; so I don't know what the compiler is complaining about.

Lastly, evidently, `.Comment.Shape.Fill.PictureEffects` doesn't work for comments.

Comment: I wonder if you can set ShapeRange.ScaleWidth to 1? There's a RelativeToOriginalSize argument.